# Why did Xcode generate an NSNumber property for my model class's boolean attribute?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, code-generation, nsmanagedobject

I created a project with Xcode, and in the .model file I created a new entity. I added to this entity an attribute named "current" of type boolean

Then I clicked Editor>Create NSManagedObject subclass, and in the file that was created, the "current" attribute is of type `NSNumber`...why is that?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * current;
```

Comment: just fyi.. you can change that behavior by selecting "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when exporting your subclass.

Answer (score 2):

That's the default. If you want scalars, you need to click the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" checkbox when it's asking you for the folder to create the file in.

Answer (score 0):

It's a number object that store 0 or 1.

SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true), this is why core data use numerical values.

**NSNumber** is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar (numeric) type. It defines a set of methods specifically for setting and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int, long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL. (Note that number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created with.) It also defines a compare: method to determine the ordering of two NSNumber objects.